# spring security sso browser

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I use Spring Security and Spring OAuth2 as authentication server for registration of the user. But I want to change on the Role of the runtime user. But I've seen on the Internet Keycloak, but we can not simply with spring. Do you have someone a recommendation, which also give Keycloak?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand. However, if you're asking if you can modify the roles returned from Keycloak in your Spring Security protected client by loading roles from another source, then answer is yes, with one caveat.

You can extend `KeycloakAuthenticationProvider` to modify the authentication before it gets stored in the Spring Security context. Take a look at [`KeycloakUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider`](https://github.com/Smartling/smartling-keycloak-extras/blob/master/keycloak-spring-security-user-details/src/main/java/org/keycloak/adapters/springsecurity/userdetails/authentication/KeycloakUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java) for inspiration.

The caveat is that these modifications are local only to the current client. You cannot modify the roles in the access token this way and it use it to call another service. If that's your intention, you may want to extend one of the SPIs in the Keycloak server instead. It's a more complex approach but the access token can be used across services that way.